# How to check if some character appears in a string?

Tags: java

I have a String of 4 character only

```
String test="CWRD"
```

I want to check if String contain all the 4 characters `"CWRD"` with any sequence of the character . So if String like this `"WRDC"` or `"RDWC"` or `"CRDW"` even then method should return true.

One way to find this by `String.contains(s)` **Or**

Convert String to Character Array and do `for` loop then check one by one one each character

```
char[] char = test.toCharArray();
for(char symbol :char ) {
 //Write Logic here
}
```

Is there any better approach to find the string is same even we change change sequence of character ?

Comment: A really nasty trick I can come up with is to sort the characters so they are always in a dependable order, then you don't need to check for different sequences.

Comment: Better in what sense?  You've already got two working solutions.

Comment: @Gimby This looks some thing promising .

Comment: @Eritrean But in this case it wont check sequence of characters ?

Comment: Sorting the characters in the string consts probably more operations than just looping over each character and checking if it exists. `String.contains` eventually will also loop over the string, so it really doesn't matter if you replace it by a for-loop. Just go with the one that is the easiest to understand.

Comment: Put all permutations of your string in a `HashSet`. This gives you an O(1) test with `contains()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be:

```
static boolean check(String str){
    return str.matches("[CWRD]{4}") && str.chars().distinct().count() == 4;
}
```

Alternativly using only regex, but not that much readable:

```
static boolean check(String str){
     return str.matches("(?!.*(.).*\\1)[CWRD]*");
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = {"CDRW","CDWR","CRDW","CRWD","CWDR","CWRD",
                    "DCRW","DCWR","DRCW","DRWC","DWCR","DWRC",
                    "RCDW","RCWD","RDCW","RDWC","RWCD","RWDC",
                    "WCDR","WCRD","WDCR","WDRC","WRCD","WRDC"};
    for(String s: str){
        System.out.println(check(s));
    }       
}
```

Comment: in this case character sequence wont impact ?

Comment: NO. It matches all combinations of your chars in any order.